# Syntax error, no apparent cause, how come? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

The following program is a snippet from an offline code generator. The program shall generate a password to the required strength. Upon debugging, the problem is highlighted at Line 10- as a syntax error, upon testing the program further, this was confirmed.

Does anyone have a clue as to why I am getting a syntax error?

```
import string
menu="Y"
wordchoice="Y"
easywords=[]

CharactersList=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
LowerList=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
SymbolsList=list(string.punctuation)

NewList=(LowerList+SymbolsList+CharactersList)

while menu == "Y":
    strength=int(input("How strong would you like your password? \n1. Weak \n2. Medium \n3. Strong"))

numchoice=0

if strength == 1:
    while wordchoice=="Y":
        numchoice=numchoice+1
        EasyPass=input("Pick your word: ")
        easywords.append(EasyPass)
        wordchoice=input("Continue? (Y/N): ")
firstWord=(random.choice(easywords))
secondWord=(random.choice(easywords))
print ("\n\n",firstWord,secondWord)
menu=input("Return to main menu? (Y/N): ")

elif strength == 2:

    Letter1=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter2=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter3=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter4=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter5=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter6=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter7=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter8=(random.choice(NewList))
    Letter9=(random.choice(NewList))

    print(Letter1,Letter2,Letter3,Letter4,Letter5,Letter6,Letter7,Letter8,Letter9)
    menu=input("\n\nCreate another password? (y/N): ")
```

Comment: Line *10*? There are errors further down, but not on line 10. The best I can guess is that you had an indentation bug, and you screwed up your indentation differently when posting it here.

Comment: `while menu == "Y": strength=int(input("How strong would you like your password? \n1. Weak \n2. Medium \n3. Strong"))` is an infinite loop since `menu` is initially `"Y"` and not mutated within the loop. And like @user2357112, I see no errors on line 10, your error isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because every elif needs to be paired with an if. You can't have an `elif` statement separated from its `if`.

To fix this, reorganize your code and make sure the `elif` directly follows the `if`.

Comment: While true, this isn't anywhere near line 10. Personally, I'd suspect a copy and paste error, with the dedented lines after the `if` block before the `elif` intended to be included in the `if` block, and only messed up in the question, not the code.

Comment: bingo, newbie mistake, sorry for the waste of time :3

Comment: @ShadowRanger He does have an infinite loop at the very beginning of his code, however this wouldn’t stop his program from initializing at all. It would just continually ask you what strength password you want.

Comment: @DanielCopley: Yar, syntax errors are at byte code compilation time, before any code in the module even runs (aside from the quirks with `__future__` imports looking like runtime stuff, but actually being byte code compile time). I just don't think the question was answerable as asked, since the line number given had no syntax errors on or even near it.